# list the operators in the forward method of module in Pytorch

Tags: module, pytorch, forward

Is there a way to list the operators used in the `forward` method of a module, something similar to `children()` for module.
I need to know if the method is applying `softmax` in `forward` and in case remove that.

Comment: Confusing question! in the forward method of the module, you can see if Softmax is used. Can you add an example to describe your need?

Comment: I want to figure out without looking at the architecture of the model. Let's say you have Net = model(). Could say if there is softmax in the forward method of Net?